# Integration TortoiseSVN and FogBugz

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, integration, fogbugz

I have read this tutorial [Integration SVN](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/60/topics/sourcecontrol/setup/TortoiseSVN.html) and setuped BugzID for the my project.

So, Currently I have another problem, My project is in development and may be added new files or modules, how do automatically add BugzID to the new files or modules ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New files and folders below the folder that you ran the script from, will automatically use the same BugzID property.  So, it should just work.
If you create a new folder that is not a sub-folder of the original folder, then you'd have to run the script on that folder too.

Here's an excerpt from the link:
"Tortoise will search up your folder path on a checkout looking for this property, so if you checkout from other folders in your tree, be sure to do the same procedure for those folders also."